# Convertir logica de BASIC a PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, basic

```
    FOR I = 1 TO N:PRINT "::::::TRAMO ";I;"::::::"
        K = W(I)*L(I)/2:K1=(C(I,I+1)+C(I+1,1))/L(I)
        V1 = K-K1+P(I)*B(I)/L(I):V2=0-(K+K1+P(I)*A(I)/L(I))
        IF SGN(V1) = SGN(V2) THEN 360:ELSE 370
    360 PRINT "V";I;">D=";ROUND(V1,-3),"V";I+1;">I: ";ROUND(V2,-3):PRINT "NO M+: "
        GOTO 460
    370 X = V1*L(I)/(V1 + ABS(V2)):IF X > A(I) THEN 380: ELSE P(I)=0
    380 M = V1*X-W(I)*X^2/2-P(I)*(X-A(I))+C(I,I+1):IF M < 0 THEN 360
        C1=(0-X)^2:C2=0-X:C3=(L(I)-X)^2:C4=(L(I)-X):K1=C(I,I+1)-M:C=M
        K2 = 0-C(I+1,I)-M:D=C1*C4-C2*C3:A=(K1*C4-K2*C2)/D:B=(K2*C1-K1*C3)/D
        Q=(B^2-4*A*C)^.5:X2=(0-B+Q)/2/A:X3=(0-B-Q)/2/A
        IF X2 < X3 THEN X4 = X + X2:X5=L(I)-(X*X3): GOTO 440
        X4=X+X3:X5=L(I)-(X+X2)
    440 PRINT "V";I;">D=";ROUND(V1,-3),"V";I+1;">I: ";ROUND(V2,-3),"M+: ";ROUND(M,-3)
        PRINT "X>";I;"=";ROUND(X4,-3),"X>";I+1;": ";ROUND(X5,-3),"X>M+: ";ROUND(X,-3)
460 NEXT I
```

Estoy intentando convertir la logica del anterior ciclo for desarrollado en BASIC, especificamente [Just Basic](https://justbasiccom.proboards.com) (no muy distinto). Estoy teniendo problemas con los GOTO, ya que a veces hay GOTO que llevan a lineas de código que están dentro de condicionales en otra linea, y claro, en BASIC esto funciona bien, pero me confunde mucho pasarlo a python. Estuve haciendo algunas pruebas peor todas consistian en repetir lineas de código y no se si eso afecte a la funcionalidad del programa, se que estamos tocando un lenguaje arcaico, pero bueno, espero contar con su ayuda.

**EDIT**
**CÓDIGO COMPLETO**

```
   'STOP :CLEAR :WAIT 5:
   INPUT "# DE TRAMOS="; N : Z = N +1
   DIM W(N),P(N),L(N),A(N),B(N),K(N),R(Z+1),C(Z+1,Z+1)
   INPUT "TIENE VOLADOS";H$ : IF H$="SI" THEN INPUT "#DEVLS."; V : ELSE 70
   FOR I=1 TO V
       PRINT "WV(";I;")=";:INPUT W(I):PRINT "LV(";I;")=";:INPUT L(I)
       PRINT "AY(";I;")=";:INPUT A(I):PRINT "PV(";I;")=";:INPUT P(I)
       M=W(I)*L(I)^2/2+P(I)*A(I)
       IF I=1 THEN C(I,I-1)=M: ELSE 65
       C(Z,Z+1)=0-M
65 NEXT I
70 FOR I=1 TO N:PRINT "W";I;"=";:INPUT W(I):PRINT "P";I;"=";:INPUT P(I)
       PRINT "L" ; I ; "=" ; : INPUT L(I):PRINT "A";I;"=";:INPUT A(I)
       PRINT "B" ; I ; "=" ; : INPUT B(I):PRINT "I";I;"=";:INPUT K(I)
        R(I)=4*K(I)/L(I)
    NEXT I
    FOR I=1 TO N
        C(I,I+1)=(W(I) * L(I) ^ 2 / 12 + P(I) * A(I) * B(I) ^ 2 / L(I) ^ 2) * -1
        C(I+1,1)= W(I) * L(I) ^ 2 / 12 + P(I) * B(I) * A(I) ^ 2 / L(I) ^ 2
    NEXT I

    FOR P=1 TO 10
        FOR I=1 TO N+1
            M1=(C(I,I-1)+C(I,I+1))*(0-R(I-1)/(R(I-1)+R(I)))
            M2=(C(I,I-1)+C(I,I+1))*(0-R(I)/(R(I-1)+R(I)))
            M3=M1*.5
            M4=M2*.5
            C(I,I+1)=C(I,I+1)+M2:C(I,I-1)=C(I,I-1)+M1
            C(I-1,I)=C(I-1,I)+M3:C(I+1,I)=C(I+1,I)+M4
        NEXT I

    NEXT P
    FOR I=1 TO N+1
        PRINT "M";I;">";I-1;"=";ROUND(C(I,I-1),-3)
        PRINT "M";I;">";I+1;"=";ROUND(C(I,I+1),-3)
    NEXT I
    FOR I = 1 TO N:PRINT "TRAMP";I
        K = W(I)*L(I)/2:K1=(C(I,I+1)+C(I+1,1))/L(I)
        V1 = K-K1+P(I)*B(I)/L(I):V2=0-(K+K1+P(I)*A(I)/L(I))
        IF SGN(V1) = SGN(V2) THEN 360:ELSE 370
    360 PRINT "V";I;">D=";ROUND(V1,-3),"V";I+1;">I=";ROUND(V2,-3):PRINT "NO M+"
        GOTO 460
    370 X = V1*L(I)/(V1 + ABS(V2)):IF X > A(I) THEN 380: ELSE P(I)=0
    380 M = V1*X-W(I)*X^2/2-P(I)*(X-A(I))+C(I,I+1):IF M < 0 THEN 360
        C1=(0-X)^2:C2=0-X:C3=(L(I)-X)^2:C4=(L(I)-X):K1=C(I,I+1)-M:C=M
        K2 = 0-C(I+1,I)-M:D=C1*C4-C2*C3:A=(K1*C4-K2*C2)/D:B=(K2*C1-K1*C3)/D
        Q=(B^2-4*A*C)^.5:X2=(0-B+Q)/2/A:X3=(0-B-Q)/2/A
        IF X2 < X3 THEN X4 = X + X2:X5=L(I)-(X*X3): GOTO 440
        X4=X+X3:X5=L(I)-(X+X2)  'was missing last )
    440 PRINT "V";I;">D=";ROUND(V1,-3),"V";I+1;">I=";ROUND(V2,-3),"M+";ROUND(M,-3)
        PRINT "X>";I;"=";ROUND(X4,-3),"X>";I+1;"=";ROUND(X5,-3),"X>M+";ROUND(X,-3)
460 NEXT I

end
'functions missing in JB
function ROUND(x, n)
    'Microsof one
    'n=3 -> 12345.678?
    'ROUND=int(x*10^n)/10^n
    'Casio FX850P one (from manual)
    'n=-2 -> 12345.7
    n=n+1
    ROUND=int(x/10^n)*10^n
end function

function SGN(x)
    SGN = (x>0)-(x<0)
end function
```

Coloco el código completo a ver si se hacen una mejor idea, tambien dejo los datos de entrada para que el código inicie y finalice correctamente:

```
NUMERO DE TRAMOS = 2
TIENE VOLADOS = NO
NUMERO DE VOLADOS = (NOT IN THIS EXAMPLE)
W1 = 2
P1 = 2
L1 = 4
A1 = 2
B1 = 2
I1 = 1
W2 = 2
P2 = 2
L2 = 4
A2 = 2
B2 = 2
I2 = 1
```

[AQUÍ](https://justbasiccom.proboards.com/thread/32/basic-release-candidate-available-download) Puede encontrar el compilador y editor de Just Basic.

Todo lo que busco es pasar la logica de ese código a python, no había colocado el código completo porque ya llevaba cierta parte, así que adjuntaré también el código que llevo traducido.

```
# Initialize empty array with a lenght
def InLi(le):
    a = [0] * (le + 1)
    return a

def SGN(n):
    numero = float(n)
    if numero == 0:
        return 0
    elif numero < 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 3

N = int(input("NÚMERO DE TRAMOS > "))
Z = N + 1
WE, HE = Z+1, Z+1;

C = [[0 for x in range(WE)] for y in range(HE)] # Initialize multi-dimensional array

W=P=L=A=B=K= InLi(N)
R = InLi(Z+1)

volados = input("¿TIENE VOLADOS? SI/NO > ")
V = "" # N volados
if volados == "SI": #GOTO 70
    V = int(input("NÚMERO DE VOLADOS > "))
    #for x in range(V):
    for x in range(1, V+1):
        W[x] = int(input("WV(" + str(x) + ") > "))
        L[x] = int(input("LV(" + str(x) + ") > "))

        A[x] = int(input("AY(" + str(x) + ") > "))
        P[x] = int(input("PV(" + str(x) + ") > "))

        M  = W[x] * pow(L[x], 2) / 2 + P[x] + A[x]
        
        if x == 1:
            C[x][x-1] = M

        C[Z][Z+1] = 0 - M

for x in range(1, N + 1):
    W[x] = int(input("W" + str(x) + " > "))
    P[x] = int(input("P" + str(x) + " > "))

    L[x] = int(input("L" + str(x) + " > "))
    A[x] = int(input("A" + str(x) + " > "))
    B[x] = int(input("B" + str(x) + " > "))
    K[x] = int(input("I" + str(x) + " > "))
    R[x] = 4 * K[x] / L[x]

for x in range(1, N + 1):
    C[x][x+1] = (W[x] * pow(L[x], 2) / 12 + P[x] * A[x] * pow(B[x], 2) / pow(L[x], 2)) * - 1
    C[x+1][1] =  W[x] * pow(L[x], 2) / 12 + P[x] * B[x] * pow(A[x], 2) / pow(L[x], 2)

for x in range(1, 10 + 1):
    for z in range(N+2):
        M1 = (C[z][z-1] + C[z][z+1]) * (-R[z-1] / (R[z-1] + R[z]))
        M2 = (C[z][z-1] + C[z][z+1]) * (-R[z] / (R[z-1] + R[z]))

        M3 = M1 * .5
        M4 = M2 * .5
        
        C[z][z+1] = C[z][z+1] + M2
        C[z][z-1] = C[z][z-1] + M1

        C[z-1][z] = C[z-1][z] + M3
        C[z+1][z] = C[z+1][z] + M4

for x in range(1, N+2):
    print("M" + str(x) + ">" + str(x-1) + round(C[x][x-1]), -3)
    print("M" + str(x) + ">" + str(x-1) + round(C[x][x+1]), -3)

for x in range(1, N + 1):
    print(":::::TRAMO " + x + " :::::")
    K = W[x] * L[x] / 2
    K1 = (C[x][x+1] + C[x+1][1]) / L[x]
    
    V1 = K - K1 + P[x] * B[x] / L[x]
    V2 = -(K + K1 + P[x] * A[x] / L[x])
```

Comment: Empieza con algunas líneas, por ejemplo con el for ``for i in range(N)`` En Python no existen las instrucciones goto, a menos que importes un paquete que haga algo similar a lo que se hace en BASIC. Mira este link [http://entrian.com/goto/]

Comment: Sí, tengo entendido eso, y ya habia buscando alternativas para usar el goto pero me parece algo "extremo", imagino que hay una forma de hacerlo sin necesidad de usar librerías externas. Yo se traducir la sintaxis, pero a la hora de ordernar los bloques de código es donde me enredo.

Comment: Esta pregunta sería mejor recibida si editaras el BASIC poniendo sólo una instrucción por línea.

Comment: deberias agregar 2 ejemplos de entrada y salida de tu programa `IF SGN(V1) = SGN(V2) THEN 360:ELSE 370` para este caso! para intentar una mejor conversion

Comment: @Bryro he actualizado la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero desenredemos el código de modo de poner una instrucción por línea:

```
    FOR I = 1 TO N
        PRINT "::::::TRAMO ";I;"::::::"
        K = W(I)*L(I)/2
        K1=(C(I,I+1)+C(I+1,1))/L(I)
        V1 = K-K1+P(I)*B(I)/L(I)
        V2=0-(K+K1+P(I)*A(I)/L(I))
        IF SGN(V1) = SGN(V2) THEN 360
        ELSE 370
    360 PRINT "V";I;">D=";ROUND(V1,-3),"V";I+1;">I: ";ROUND(V2,-3):PRINT "NO M+: "
        GOTO 460
    370 X = V1*L(I)/(V1 + ABS(V2))
        IF X > A(I) THEN 380
        ELSE P(I)=0
    380 M = V1*X-W(I)*X^2/2-P(I)*(X-A(I))+C(I,I+1)
        IF M < 0 THEN 360
        C1=(0-X)^2:C2=0-X
        C3=(L(I)-X)^2
        C4=(L(I)-X)
        K1=C(I,I+1)-M
        C=M
        K2 = 0-C(I+1,I)-M
        D=C1*C4-C2*C3
        A=(K1*C4-K2*C2)/D
        B=(K2*C1-K1*C3)/D
        Q=(B^2-4*A*C)^.5
        X2=(0-B+Q)/2/A
        X3=(0-B-Q)/2/A
        IF X2 < X3 THEN X4 = X + X2: X5=L(I)-(X*X3): GOTO 440
        X4=X+X3
        X5=L(I)-(X+X2)

    440 PRINT "V";I;">D=";ROUND(V1,-3),"V";I+1;">I: ";ROUND(V2,-3),"M+: ";ROUND(M,-3)
        PRINT "X>";I;"=";ROUND(X4,-3),"X>";I+1;": ";ROUND(X5,-3),"X>M+: ";ROUND(X,-3)
460 NEXT I
```

A continuación apliquemos transformaciones. Convertire en comentarios las líneas transformadas. El comentario en Python se marca con "#".

El `FOR` en Python es `for i in range(inicio, final):` que recorre desde `inicio` hasta `final - 1`

```
# FOR I = 1 TO N
for i in range(1, n + 1):
```

Los `PRINT` in Python se escriben `print(exp1, exp2, ...)`. Convertire sólo el primero:

```
#    PRINT "::::::TRAMO ";I;"::::::"
    print("::::::TRAMO ", I ,"::::::")
```

Las comparaciones de igualdad van con "==" en Python, y las listas (arreglos) se indexan con `[]`:

```
#    IF SGN(V1) = SGN(V2) THEN 360
#    ELSE 370
```

se convierte en:

```
    if sgn[v1] == sgv[v2]:
# 360 PRINT "V";I;">D=";ROUND(V1,-3),"V";I+1;">I: ";ROUND(V2,-3):PRINT "NO M+: "
#     GOTO 460
        PRINT "V";I;">D=";ROUND(V1,-3),"V";I+1;">I: ";ROUND(V2,-3):PRINT "NO M+: "
        continue
```

[En Python los indices parten de cero, no de 1. No ajuste el código para esto.]

El `GOTO 460` lleva directamente a la siguiente iteración del `for`. Eso se hace en Python con un `continue`.

En el siguiente `IF` simplemente invierto la comparación para hacer la asignación:

```
#    IF X > A(I) THEN 380
#    ELSE P(I)=0

    if x <= a[i]:
        p(i) = 0
```

Para el siguiente `IF` me limitare a duplicar las líneas que se ejecutan en el Label 360:

```
#    IF M < 0 THEN 360

    if m < 0 then:
        PRINT "V";I;">D=";ROUND(V1,-3),"V";I+1;">I: ";ROUND(V2,-3):PRINT "NO M+: "
        continue
```

El último `IF`, separando las instrucciones en líneas, se vería asi

```
   IF X2 < X3 THEN 
        X4 = X + X2
        X5=L(I)-(X*X3)
        GOTO 440
    X4=X+X3
    X5=L(I)-(X+X2)
```

lo que es equivalente a:

```
    if X2 < X3:
        X4 = X + X2
        X5=L(I)-(X*X3)
#        GOTO 440
    else:
        X4=X+X3
        X5=L(I)-(X+X2)
```

Resumiendo, el programa queda así:

```
    # FOR I = 1 TO N
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
    #    PRINT "::::::TRAMO ";I;"::::::"
        print("::::::TRAMO ", I ,"::::::")
        K = W(I)*L(I)/2
        K1=(C(I,I+1)+C(I+1,1))/L(I)
        V1 = K-K1+P(I)*B(I)/L(I)
        V2=0-(K+K1+P(I)*A(I)/L(I))
    #    IF SGN(V1) = SGN(V2) THEN 360
    #    ELSE 370

        if sgn[v1] == sgv[v2]:
    # 360 PRINT "V";I;">D=";ROUND(V1,-3),"V";I+1;">I: ";ROUND(V2,-3):PRINT "NO M+: "
            PRINT "V";I;">D=";ROUND(V1,-3),"V";I+1;">I: ";ROUND(V2,-3):PRINT "NO M+: "
            continue

        X = V1*L(I)/(V1 + ABS(V2)) # Label 370

    #    IF X > A(I) THEN 380
    #    ELSE P(I)=0
        if x <= a[i]:
            p(i) = 0

        M = V1*X-W(I)*X^2/2-P(I)*(X-A(I))+C(I,I+1) # Label 380

    #    IF M < 0 THEN 360
        if m < 0 then:
            PRINT "V";I;">D=";ROUND(V1,-3),"V";I+1;">I: ";ROUND(V2,-3):PRINT "NO M+: "
            continue

        C1=(0-X)^2:C2=0-X
        C3=(L(I)-X)^2
        C4=(L(I)-X)
        K1=C(I,I+1)-M
        C=M
        K2 = 0-C(I+1,I)-M
        D=C1*C4-C2*C3
        A=(K1*C4-K2*C2)/D
        B=(K2*C1-K1*C3)/D
        Q=(B^2-4*A*C)^.5
        X2=(0-B+Q)/2/A
        X3=(0-B-Q)/2/A
        if X2 < X3:
            X4 = X + X2
            X5=L(I)-(X*X3)
    #        GOTO 440
        else:
            X4=X+X3
            X5=L(I)-(X+X2)

        PRINT "V";I;">D=";ROUND(V1,-3),"V";I+1;">I: ";ROUND(V2,-3),"M+: ";ROUND(M,-3) # Label 440
        PRINT "X>";I;"=";ROUND(X4,-3),"X>";I+1;": ";ROUND(X5,-3),"X>M+: ";ROUND(X,-3)
#460 NEXT I
```

Queda pendiente:

1. Convertir los `A(i)` en `a[i]` y ajustar de Option Base con cero o uno ... no se.
2. Convertir los `PRINT a;b;c` a `print(a, b, c)`
3. Convertir todas las palabras claves `IF`, `ELSE`, `PRINT` a minúsculas.

**Disclaimer**

1. Probablemente hay errores en la transcripción. Este es solo un punto de partida.
2. No hay garantía de que produzca el mismo resultado que Basic.

Comment: Ok esto es un gran paso, solo tengo una pequeña aclaración, cuando pones `if x <= a(i): p(i) = 0` sería `if x <= a[i]: p[i] = 0` porque son listas no tuplas. Voy a probar y vuelvo para avisar como se comportó el código.

Comment: Si, correcto. Se me pasaron algunos cambios en los `if` y deje sin tocar los cálculos. Sólo me preocupe de reflejar bien los `if` y `goto`.

Comment: Bueno, paso a informar que el código funciona tal cual como debe funcionar, muchisimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez una mezcla de BASIC y Python (lo cual en fin es ninguno) le ayude con ese codigo espagueti:

```
FOR I = 1 TO N:
        PRINT "::::::TRAMO ";I;"::::::"
        K = W(I)*L(I)/2:K1=(C(I,I+1)+C(I+1,1))/L(I)
        V1 = K-K1+P(I)*B(I)/L(I):V2=0-(K+K1+P(I)*A(I)/L(I))
        IF SGN(V1) = SGN(V2) THEN 
           GOSUB S360
        ELSE
           X = V1*L(I)/(V1 + ABS(V2)):
           IF X > A(I) THEN 
             ' Nada
           ELSE 
              P(I)=0
           M = V1*X-W(I)*X^2/2-P(I)*(X-A(I))+C(I,I+1):
           IF M < 0 THEN 
               GOSUB S360
           ELSE
              C1=(0-X)^2:C2=0-X:C3=(L(I)-X)^2:C4=(L(I)-X):K1=C(I,I+1)-M:C=M
              K2 = 0-C(I+1,I)-M:D=C1*C4-C2*C3:A=(K1*C4-K2*C2)/D:B=(K2*C1-K1*C3)/D
              Q=(B^2-4*A*C)^.5:X2=(0-B+Q)/2/A:X3=(0-B-Q)/2/A
           IF X2 < X3 THEN 
              X4 = X + X2:X5=L(I)-(X*X3): 
           ELSE
              X4=X+X3:X5=L(I)-(X+X2)
    440 PRINT "V";I;">D=";ROUND(V1,-3),"V";I+1;">I: ";ROUND(V2,-3),"M+: ";ROUND(M,-3)
        PRINT "X>";I;"=";ROUND(X4,-3),"X>";I+1;": ";ROUND(X5,-3),"X>M+: ";ROUND(X,-3)
460 NEXT I

SUB S360
           PRINT "V";I;">D=";
           ROUND(V1,-3),"V";
           I+1;">I: ";
           ROUND(V2,-3):PRINT "NO M+: "
RETURN
```

Añnadé el GOSUB en lugar de un GOTO dentro de la condicional.

Comment: En la linea ` 370 X = V1 * L(I) / (V1 + ABS(V2)) : IF X > A(I) THEN 380 : ELSE P(I) = 0` si hace algo cuando se cumple la condición, `THEN 380` dice que vaya a la linea 380, es decir: `M = V1 * X - W(I) * X ^ 2 / 2 - P(I) * (X-A(I)) + C(I,I+1) : IF M < 0 THEN 360`.